# Method for verifying xcopy has copied all files

Tags: cmd, directory, compare

After I copy an entire directory using xcopy, I want to verify that all the files got copied across as it often seems to fail. I'm trying to do it by looping through each file in the source directory and then checking it exists in the destination directory.

I have something that seems to work on my machine but doesn't seem to on the build machine, which is where I need it.

```
@echo off
set /a count=0
set /a count2=0
for /r "C:\work\DLS\built\Android_EU\data" %%f in (*) do (set /a count+=1
)

for /r "C:\work\DLS\TegraProject\DLS\assets" %%f in (*) do (set /a count2+=1
)

echo count is %count%
echo count 2 is %count2%

if %count%==%count2% echo equal
if not %count%==%count2% echo not equal

pause

if %count%==%count2% exit 0
if not %count%==%count2% exit 1
```

I checked manually and there are 594 files in both folders on both machines.

It's reported correctly on my machine.

On the build machine, it says there are 583 and 584 files. Is there any reason that would skip files?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Any basic copy command will fail on files which are open or locked in another program.  However if you use `Robocopy` which is an Xcopy replacement then it provides a summary at the end to show the stats.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have replaced with Robocopy and it seems to have worked a few times in a row. I could be mistaken but I'm pretty sure I was trying Robocopy yesterday though and it also didn't always work. I think it would be a good exercise to do this post copy verification regardless.

Comment: Robocopy will give you the summary and also set an errorlevel that you can check.  If you want to confirm it manually, what will you do if a file was copied but is zero bytes?  What level of checking do you want?

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive. I've come up with something but it doesn't seem to work on a particular machine and I'm not sure why. I've edited my question.

Comment: Recheck the number of files on the machine with `dir /b /a-d |find /c /v ""`

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive, I think I can just check error level against 1 as files should always be copied as the tree is deleted beforehand. I'm curious to know why my manual verification could have failed though, purely for my own understanding.

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive, dir /s /b /a-d |find /c /v "" correctly returns 594 on both directories. Is there a way I can assign that to a variable like I did in my attempt?

Comment: A reason why a file was skipped is if the `hidden` attribute was set on a file in one of the folder.  The method I showed counts hidden files too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it will work up to `2^31 -1` files. :)

```
@echo off
set "count="
set "count2="

for /f %%a in (' dir "C:\work\DLS\built\Android_EU\data"   /s /b /a-d ^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a
for /f %%a in (' dir "C:\work\DLS\TegraProject\DLS\assets" /s /b /a-d ^|find /c /v "" ') do set count2=%%a

echo count is %count%
echo count 2 is %count2%

if %count% EQU %count2% echo equal
if %count% NEQ %count2% echo not equal

pause

if %count% EQU %count2% exit 0
if not %count% NEQ %count2% exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive. With that code, on my machine it returns 2 and 1 and on the build machine it returns 3 and 1 :-/. I have an alternative method that seems to work so I'll post that now.

Comment: This now also counts files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this seems to work- thanks for your input @foxidrive.

```
cd C:\work\DLS\built\Android_EU\data
dir /s /b /a-d |find /c /v "" > temp.txt
set /p count=<temp.txt
cd C:\work\DLS\TegraProject\DLS\assets\data
dir /s /b /a-d |find /c /v "" > temp.txt
set /p count2=<temp.txt

echo count is %count%
echo count 2 is %count2%

pause

if %count%==%count2% exit 0
if not %count%==%count2% exit 1
```

Comment: This seems to work now if running from the build machine directly- robocopy succeeds, my verification succeeds and when I manually check, there are 594 files. But when I try to invoke the script via the continuous integration software Bamboo, robocopy succeeds, my verification succeeds but when I manually check, there are much less than 594 files :-/.

Comment: The code you have shown will not produce a different answer.  Are these folders live and changing?  There has to be a good reason - like some other process is putting files in or removing them.

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive. They will be eventually but I'm checking this in isolation. The copy is done so at the point I'm testing there are 595 files in both directories if I look manually. When I run a batch file with my code in the values are correct (595 and 595). When I run a batch file with your code in the values are 3 and 1. I'm not sure what the difference could be but there does appear to be one. But even with my code, there still seems to be an issue with using Bamboo where the files aren't copied but all the verification succeeds, but that must be a completely separate issue :-/.

Comment: I didn't mention there are multiple subdirectories within the data folder but maybe that makes a difference to your code?
For example there is:

C:\work\DLS\TegraProject\DLS\assets\data\anims

C:\work\DLS\TegraProject\DLS\assets\data\models\player\body

etc